# YUMI Ubuntu 16.04 64 Bit USB to SSD

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, live-usb

long time Windows user here. Last week I got fed up with Windows 10 and so I used YUMI to create a bootable Ubuntu 16.04 64 Bit USB stick.

So far, I love what I see!
I installed some software and tried a few things...

Now my question is, can I buy myself a new SSD and install/transfer my YUMI USB Ubuntu on it...
So that I do not need to install all the software again and setup all the things I have done so far on the USB Ubuntu...

Any advise / help would be welcome!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment asking for clarification, so I'll assume that you're going to put the SSD inside the PC, rather than connect it as an external disk.

First, boot from your bootable USB and double-click the install icon. Select the SSD as the target disk and install Ubuntu onto it. Once it's done installing, don't restart the computer.
Open the `/var/cache/apt/archives` folder and copy its contents to somewhere on the SSD, for example `/home/user/Desktop/`. Then, go to the home folder on the USB, push Ctrl-H to show hidden files, and copy all the files in the home folder to `/home/user/` on the SSD. As well as your personal files, this will also copy application settings, caches and the like.

Now all the files are on the SSD, you just need to reinstall your software.
Reboot the machine and start from the SSD. Navigate to `/home/user/Desktop` (or wherever you saved the `.deb` files to) in the file manager. Right-click the window and choose "Open in Terminal". Once the terminal opens, enter the command

```
sudo dpkg -i *.deb
```

and press enter. All your software will be installed onto the SSD. Once the command finishes, you can delete all the `.deb` files that you copied: you very likely won't need to use them again.

You shouldn't need to restart the computer after installing the software.

Comment: I will try this once I can logon to my linux again :(

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/360974/yumi-ubuntu-16-04-stick-cannot-login-anymore

Comment: Install Ubuntu on the SSD, mount the casper-rw file and copy over the files that way. If you're having trouble doing that, or if you're now not sure where to put them, comment and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: thanks, i will get to that part once I figure out what I want to start with...

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not a great idea.  Simply copying over the deb archives may not be representative of every package that has been installed.  Much easier to capture the installed packages with this at the Terminal: `dpkg --get-selections | grep -w install$ > dpkg-get-selection.txt` then installing fresh onto the SSD, then install the required packages at the new install's Terminal: `sudo dpkg --set-selections | grep -w install$ < /path/to/dpkg-get-selection.txt && sudo apt-get -u dselect-upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

> I installed some software and tried a few things

I'll assume you didn't use a persistent Live CD.

In which case, once you restart, everything you did will be gone.

> can I buy myself a new SSD and install/transfer my YUMI USB Ubuntu on it

Sure. **OR**, you could install & use GParted (might already be there), and make a partition alongside Windows to install Ubuntu (or another Linux distro of your choice)